# Баг с кодировкой на php

Tags: php, кодировка

Не могу настроить правильно кодировку. Вот мой код:

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: text/html; charset="utf-8"');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'Russian');
$month = strftime("%B");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    echo $month;
  ?>
</body>
</html>')
```

Использую openserver. Когда пишу `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'Russian');` вместо месяца выдаются символы чёрных ромбов с вопросами, любой другой язык выдаётся нормально. В чём дело? (Подозреваю сервер, но незнаю, что там менять.)

Answer (score 2):

Обратите внимание на кодировку самого файла, который содержит русский текст. Должна быть *UTF-8 w/o BOM*.

Answer (score 2):

Интересно, что в вопросе русским по белому написано, что проблема с функцией strftime().

И если чуть-чуть погуглить, то найдется [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2199161/285587), в котором объясняется, что под виндой корректного поведения этой функции с кодировкой utf-8 добиться невозможно.

То есть, под никсами все должно работать (при установке соответствующих локалей, разумеется). Например для стандартной установки я бы писал так

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
```

Answer (score -1):

Напишите в начале файла:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Ну вот всё прописано, проблема именно с русский языком, все остальные выбранные языки в local работают, а в русский почему то нет...

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> setlocale(LC_ALL, 'Russian');
> ```

Вероятно, это стоит убрать. А файл с кодом сохранить в UTF8.